# How to get 12V DC from 110V AC inside a gang box?

Tags: electrical, switch, ceiling-fan

I have an A23 battery (12V) powered wall fan control, [link](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-3-Speed-Universal-Ceiling-Fan-Wireless-Wall-Control-Damp-Rated-98139/313485917). Because I got tired of replacing batteries every year, I'm looking into a way getting power from the 110V wires behind the switch.

[This](https://community.smartthings.com/t/home-decorators-ceiling-fan-light-controller-mr101z-first-impressions/81408/184) post has done it, see attached photo below. They used an old 12v phone charger, built a cardboard housing and soldered it to the switch board.

But is that code compliant? I'm in California. If not, what modifications could I do to make it code compliant? Maybe 3D printed case instead of cardboard? Or maybe a UL listed tiny enclosure? Or if DIY isn't a code compliant option, is there any UL listed AC to DC converter that could be installed inside an electrical box? From a quick search I found [this](https://www.solidapollo.com/in-wall-power-supply-12v-0.2a-9w.html) but it doesn't seem to be UL listed and it costs more than I'm willing to spend.

Note using a different fan control isn't an option since I have paired this wall switch with a Zigbee enabled fan control, [link](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-Universal-Wink-Enabled-White-Ceiling-Fan-Premier-Remote-Control-99432/206591100). I'd like to keep the costs low and reuse my existing Zigbee fan controls and switches. If that's not option I'd entertain the idea replacing my fan switches with something else that could be paired at the same frequency with my existing Zigbee enabled fan controls.

[image]

Comment: At least I’m not aware of a code compliant solution and I was looking for something similar recently. Could you bring in low voltage wires and a GFCI outlet with charger in attic/crawlspace? Note even then you’d need a split high voltage/low-voltage box

Comment: That's a good idea but unfortunately because of the closet there is no space on the wall to fit a 2-gang box that it seems I need to split high and low voltage. If I had space for a 2-gang box I'd have gone with 2 separate hardwired smart switches for light and fan like I did for the other bedroom. A few years ago I went with this Zigbeen fan control because that was the only option at the time to have dimmable light and fan smart controlled and from a wall switch. Doing a quick search now there doesn't seem to be a smart switch that fits in one gang and can dim lights and control fan speed.

Comment: I wanted a similar thing (to control my pellet stove) so I used a black box power supply that was from a telephone - about a 1" cube that I was able to cut the mains plug bit off and solder the connections.

Comment: You can't fit a new box on the wall below the switch?  Got a pic of the actual switch and box on the wall?

Comment: @user162793 I am not clear about your setup. What do you currently have? Where is the "closet" showing up all of the sudden? What do the wires have to do with the boxes? What I mean: In the crawl space/attic, you generate your 12V in a code compliant way and fish a low-voltage cable to where the switch is. If the switch is currently in a 1-gang box, what's the problem? If the switch is currently in a 2-gang box (which doesn't seem to be the case), why can't you replace it with a 1gang+low voltage version? I've done this numerous times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is that code compliant?

LOL, not even slightly.  I imagine the guy went with cardboard because of not being able to find any matchsticks or fireworks or white phosphorous to stick inside that electrical box.  LOL SMH

If the box was entirely low-voltage kit, and wasn't sharing the box with 120VAC circuits, it would be far less outrageous - code is pretty mellow on boxes which contain only low-voltage things.

So if I needed to do what you're trying to do there, I would install it Western Electric style (the way Princess phones used to be powered).   I'd install it in a standalone junction box (not one sharing with 120VAC circuits) then run thermostat cable from the device to some utility location where it's appropriate to have a low-voltage wall wart plugged into a 120V socket.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought. I was hoping for a UL listed power supply that can be installed inside the box like the one I linked to but that seems to only be CE certified. What you suggested is more hassle than changing batteries every year so I'll continue doing that. I also tried earlier today the Harbor Breeze UC9051T wired wall switch that I have in another room but I couldn't make it work after trying all dip switches combinations.

Comment: @user162793 I doubt it's CE certified as in *Committee Europeiene* since it does not say "made in Germany", and you didn't get it direct from an EU maker. In the rest of the world, CE is certainly faked.   IIRC on those models, the DIP switches select fan number, which must match the transmitter.  However that's only promised to work with a controller/remote pair, not every model with that brand name. HB is a Lowes house brand, every model is built by a different manufacturer, there's no engineering department keeping controls consistent.

Comment: It seems to have the correct CE mark with proper spacing between the letters and not the fake CE that means Chine Export but as you said it could very likely be fake, If you happen to come across a UL listed alternative please let me know.

Comment: I found https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TRACO-Power/TIW-12-112?qs=ckJk83FOD0U1OE%252Bio%252BGhcA%3D%3D that seems to be UL listed? It's a bit expensive though.

Comment: @user162793 The "CE with the proper spacing" is a myth. Many entirely faked CE's have the correct geometry, and anyway even Siemens could fake CE on goods it ships outside the EU. EU does not enforce outside the EU.  Mouser sells *components* which are not *equipment* in the NEC 110.2 meaning.  UL uses a separate mark called "UR" (reversed) for components.  CSA and ETL use the same mark, which can ve very confusing. Properly listed *equipment* will include instructions and labeling on how to wire it into a house, which you must follow per NEC 110.3(B).

Answer (score 0):

Get a fan controller with the features you want including ZigBee that is mains powered not 12V.  The PSU is built in.

OR

Get one that is battery powered and not designed to be in a wall box.  Plug it into a wall outlet if you want, Velcro it to the cover plate of that box if you want.  Do whatever you want outside this box.

Comment: It doesn't seem there is any zigbee or zwave fan controller paired with a wired wall switch. An alternative would be a non smart fan controller paired with a wired wall switch and have the Bond Bridge but the costs add up so I'll keep what I have and continue changing batteries every year. Regarding your 2nd suggestion there is no close by outlet and it would look ugly having a wired fan remote mounted on the wall with visible wires going to it.